# Trigger.io third party native modules

Tags: android, ios, native, trigger.io, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using Trigger.io for my app, for more than a year now. I saw Trigger.io developing from very first days before I decided to go with it. I was very excited when native modules were introduced. Since then I saw only few native modules in public domain, most of them are by Trigger.io, and I love them!

My question is... is there any good resources, repositories for Trigger.io native modules by third party developers. I looked at Github, but nothing much is happening there.

Maybe we can start sharing our findings here? If this is current 'to go' place for trigger.io community...

Answer (score 0):

It would be great to see more community resources for 3rd party Trigger.io module development!

If there is anything we can do from our side to contribute to such an effort please let us know.

If anyone is looking for sample code all of the Trigger.io module sources are available on Github:

https://github.com/trigger-corp/

We're also always happy to receive pull requests! :)